# Rest call from Service class in android

Tags: android

Is it possible to call a URL with HttpURLConnection from a service class? I haven't been able to implement it by adding it to onStartCommand().

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me how to implement it. whether in separate thread or any method?

Comment: Yes you need a separate thread in the Service or you can use IntentService directly.